# On Uno Platform how do you use Preferences.Set command

Tags: xamarin, uno, xamarin.essentials

I have an existing Xamarin app which uses
Preferences.Set("xxx","yyy");
which is in Xamarin.Essentials
It works OK Android, iOs and UWP.
When I add as WASM project to run the project in Browser this command does not work.

Comment: You should change your tag from uno to uno-platform so your question gets flagged by Uno team and community. Uno alone is unfortunately too generic.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin Essentials only provides implementations for iOS, Android, and UWP. So in Platform Uno you are going to have to provide your own implementations for other platforms such as WASM, WPF, macOS, and Tizen.